# Sum a number with divisors to get another number

Tags: algorithms

There are two numbers A and B, in each step we can sum A with one of its divisors expect 1 and A. We want to get from A to B, what is the minimum step that we can get B?

Note: Sometimes we can't get to B from A.  If, say, $A,B$ are both primes then it is clear that we can not achieve this. In the cases where it is possible,  I want an algorithm that solve this problem.

Edit: Consider Z=A in each step sum Z with one of the divisors Z expect 1 and Z to get B

$4≤A≤B≤100000$

Example: A=4, B=24

$$4\to 6\to 8\to 12\to 18\to 24$$

As you can see the answer is 5 for this example.

Comment: Must the divisor be of the original $A$ or the current $A$ ?

Comment: So we can sum $A$ with divisors of $B$ to reach $B$?

Comment: @SamAnderson Consider Z=A in each step sum Z with one of the divisors Z expect 1 and Z to get B

Comment: So we sum $A$ with divisors of  the original $A$ to reach $B$? How in your example do you then go from $12 \rightarrow 18$, or do you just sum with $4$ and then $2$ or what?

Comment: There will not always be a solution, it is interesting to find the exact conditions for a solution

Comment: @AntoinedePaladin Sometimes we can't get B from A  print -1

Comment: @SamAnderson $6$ is $4$ plus any one non-trivial factor of $4$, namely two, then $8$ is $6$ plus any one non-trivial factor of $6$, and so on. At each stage, you have a choice of which factor you want to choose for the sum. For example, from $6$ we could also go to $9$ by adding $3$, another non-trivial factor of $6$.

Comment: Okay so the factors are taken from the current sum, not the original number.

Comment: @lulu When viewed as a number theory problem this is not gibberish. Suppose that we have two non-primes that both have very large number of factors and they are not *close* in some well defined way. Then the question of the existence of this procedure can be raised. And the question of the number of steps as a function of $A$ and $B$ can be raised. This does not look trivial to me.

Comment: I repeat:  this seems clearly to have been taken from a coding competition.  The incoherent presentation of the problem seems like evidence of that.  If I am wrong, fine.  But, then, what is the source of the problem?

Comment: @lulu this question is taken from quera.ir site but this site is a persian site.

Comment: @lulu Sorry for my bad English

Comment: Never apologize for that, my Farsi is a lot worse.  Let me apologize instead for mistaking a translation for something else.  I will take a look at the question with fresh eyes now.

Comment: I am looking at the Greedy Algorithm, which takes the largest possible divisor at each stage.  Have you found a case in which that one does not work?  I expect this fails...I haven't looked at much.

Comment: The question solves in [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46431198/sum-a-number-with-divisors-to-get-another-number/46432338#46432338). Thanks marvel308 for solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This obviously doesn't work when $A$ or $B$ or both are prime, so that's an important addendum.

My first thought for an algorithm would be to create a tree of some kind, marking each step with an ordering that works (so you can backtrack easily) then using the $gcd(a,b)$ function to add the highest factor you can and checking whether that was okay and then marking that as well.

Then you have in your tree structure both the factors that you've tried, and the steps that you've tried. Then if you realize that it didn't work with this highest factor you backtrack to the latest factor that was marked okay, at the latest step that was marked okay. Then continue from there until you reach your sum.

This problem relies on information that we can't know in the present time, if I add a factor to the sum then I will most likely have different factors next time etc. I would conjecture that the running time for the optimal algorithm here is non-polynomial so a brute-force tactic with some sort of tree is probably in that case your best bet. It would still be rather quick for small numbers.